# Как обновить webdriver?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, windows-7, chromedriver

Вот такая ошибка возникает при запуске любого скрипта с Selenium на Python:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 106
Current browser version is 109.0.5414.120 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Ответ на такой простой вопрос, как же обновить webdriver, я так и не нашел. Скачал версию webdriver, там exe, что с ним делать - не понимаю.

В код импортирую webdriver отсюда, но exe там нет:

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver
```

Я знаю еще, чо можно в коде конкретно указать путь к chromedriver.exe, но это неудобно каждый раз делать. Как сделать по-нормальному?